# Evaluation of $\sqrt[3]{40+11\sqrt{13}}+\sqrt[3]{40-11\sqrt{13}}$

Tags: arithmetic, radicals

> Evaluate
> $$\sqrt[3]{40+11\sqrt{13}}+\sqrt[3]{40-11\sqrt{13}}$$

The solution is $5$.

Suppose $\sqrt[3]{40+11\sqrt{13}}=A, \sqrt[3]{40-11\sqrt{13}}=B$

We have
$$A^3+B^3=80, A^3-B^3=22\sqrt{13}$$

Two unknowns, two equations, so we should be able to solve for $A+B$ (what we want).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint 1

$$A^3+B^3=(A+B)((A+B)^2-3AB)$$

Hint 2

$$AB=3$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $x = \sqrt[3]{40 + 11\sqrt{13}} + \sqrt[3]{40 - 11\sqrt{13}}$. Then we have that
\begin{align*}
x^{3} = 80 + 9x & \Longleftrightarrow x^{3} - 9x - 80 = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x^{3} - 25x) + (16x - 80) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x(x^{2} - 25) + 16(x  - 5) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x(x + 5)(x - 5) + 16(x - 5) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x^{2} + 5x + 16)(x - 5) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x = 5
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps !

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\sqrt[3]{40+11\sqrt{13}}=\frac{5+\sqrt{13}}{2}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{40-11\sqrt{13}}=\frac{5-\sqrt{13}}{2}$$